SwiftUI disable SideBar in NavigationSplitView detail
I'm using a published variable to programmatically show / hide the side bar of my NavigationSplitView when showing / hiding the detail.
NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $fetcher.columnVisibility) {
    SideView()
} detail: {
    DetailView()
        .onAppear {
            fetcher.columnVisibility = .all
        }
        .onDisappear {
            if isVision {
                fetcher.columnVisibility = .detailOnly
            }
        }
    }
}

It works great in visionOS, but in iOS I still can see the button to open the side panel (or even pull it out by swiping right from the left edge). Is there any way to completely hide & disable the side panel?
